# handling enter press in <asp:textbox

Tags: asp.net, form-submit

I have an asp.net textbox which I want to use as a search box.

I wasn't planning on having a button, just allowing the user to type their search keywords into the textbox and press enter.

```
<div id="search-bar">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

How can I get the "enter press" to call a method, or post back the page with keywords in URL parameters, e.g. `search.aspx?keywords=this&that`?

Answer (score 6):

Set [AutoPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx) to true if you want to call a function in codebehind [OnTextChanged](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCsQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx&ei=9s3jTI2rCNG14QbyoOyKBQ&usg=AFQjCNGkhvuCX0CwnQBM80x_1Vo2BMGlNQ&sig2=Ix-rN068mCon6_BwNVssLA). This will occur if the Textbox loses focus(f.e. <kbd>Tab</kbd>-key) or **<kbd>Enter</kbd>-Key is pressed**.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways you can set a default button using the form object DefaultButton property or the DefaultButton property of a panel, but I have found them to be unreliable in the past in various browsers so usually I rely on javascript, if you don't want the button visible you can just set the visible property to false.

The only downside to this code is you have to turn off event validation with a page directive, but it should fire off click events, and trigger validators and all that.

Here is an example the code that we use.  Normally I would put the register function in a utility class, but for this example it is in the page code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void cmdSubmit1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litValue.Text = "Value 1 - You entered: " + txtValue1.Text;
    }
    protected void cmdSubmit2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litValue.Text = "Value 2 - You entered: " + txtValue2.Text;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function registers what button is clicked based on whatever control currently has focus
    /// so for example if the user password field has focus then you can cause the enter button to click
    /// if the enter key is pressed This works with ie and firefox as far as I know
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ControlWithFocus"></param>
    /// <param name="ControlToClick"></param>
    private void RegisterDefaultButton(System.Web.UI.Control ControlWithFocus, System.Web.UI.Control ControlToClick)
    {

        PostBackOptions p = new PostBackOptions(ControlToClick);
        p.PerformValidation = true;
        if (ControlToClick is Button)
        {
            p.ValidationGroup = ((Button)ControlToClick).ValidationGroup;
        }
        else if (ControlToClick is ImageButton)
        {
            p.ValidationGroup = ((ImageButton)ControlToClick).ValidationGroup;
        }
        else if (ControlToClick is LinkButton)
        {
            p.ValidationGroup = ((LinkButton)ControlToClick).ValidationGroup;
        }

        p.RequiresJavaScriptProtocol = false;

        AttributeCollection a = null;
        if (ControlWithFocus is HtmlControl)
        {
            a = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl)ControlWithFocus).Attributes;
        }
        else if (ControlWithFocus is WebControl)
        {
            a = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl)ControlWithFocus).Attributes;
        }

        if (a != null)
        {
            a["onKeyDown"] = string.Format("if (event.keyCode == 13) {{{0}}}"
                  , ControlToClick.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(p));
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterDefaultButton(txtValue1, cmdSubmit1);
        RegisterDefaultButton(txtValue2, cmdSubmit2);

    }

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        Enter Value 1: <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Enter Value 2: <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <asp:Literal ID="litValue" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdSubmit1" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="cmdSubmit1_Click">Hidden Button 1</asp:LinkButton>
        <input id="cmdSubmit2" runat="server" visible="false" type="button" value="Hidden Button 2" onserverclick="cmdSubmit2_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

to submit a form with javascript is:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

but asp usually puts a whole bunch of javascript in the click for buttons to do with viewstate and things like that, so you might be better off adding a button that is set as the default for the form, and then hiding it with CSS.